# How to "center in-game camera" on some node? I'm using Xcode 6 and Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I "center in-game camera" on any SKNode? I'm using Xcode 6, SpriteKit and Swift.

Comment: This is explained in the Sprite Kit Programming Guide and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828655/how-to-make-camera-follow-sknode-in-sprite-kit

Comment: @LearnCocos2D can You please see my another question? It is very important. Please if You have 2 minutes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117368

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
 func centerOnNode(node:SKNode){

       let cameraPositionInScene:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: mazeWorld!)

       mazeWorld!.position = CGPoint(x:mazeWorld!.position.x - cameraPositionInScene.x, y: mazeWorld!.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y)
   }


   override func didSimulatePhysics() {
      self.centerOnNode(hero!)
  }
```